# checkbox value always give "false" in jquery.serializeJSON plugin

Tags: javascript, serialization

In my code i used jquery.serializeJSON plugin.if i checked it or not this always gives "false" value. how can I fix this?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="loyalty-rule-active" name="status[bool]" data-unchecked-value="false"
                                                           class="form-control" required/>
```

In javascript code,

```
$('form').serializeJSON();
```

Comment: try removing: data-unchecked-value="false"

Comment: it remove but gives "false"

Comment: I want to store this checkbox value as boolean in database.but it default come as string.I want to convert it to boolean value

Comment: @maneesha5 you can check my answer and jsfiddle attached there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `value` attribute for your `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="loyalty-rule-active" name="status[bool]" 
data-unchecked-value="false" value="true" class="form-control" required/>
```

This will give you `true` (from `value` attribute) when checked and `false` (from `data-unchecked-value` attribute ) when unchecked in `$('form').serializeJSON();`

Here is the link to working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rr7t3t1k/) that shows the above working example.

Comment: I added it.but it gives only false.

Comment: but there is a problem. if i don't check it it gives nothing. can you help this